# Is "how long are you here for" formal or informal?

Tags: formality

What exactly is the difference in meaning of the following sentences?

> 1. How long are you here for?
> 2. How long have you been here?
> 3. Since when have you been here?
> 4. How long will you be here?

I think "how long are you here for" talks about the present (perfect) and the future time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is..... Is **“how long are you here for” formal or informal?**

I would say **informal**  “How long will you be here for” sounds more formal in my opinion.

The question is.....**What exactly is the difference in meaning of the following sentences?**

> How long are you here for?
>
> How long have you been here?
>
> Since when have you been here?
>
> How long will you be here?

The difference in meaning is **How much longer will you be here**, **How long have you already been here**, **When did you arrive** The fourth item is just a repeat of the first question but in a different form.

Comment: I don't know why somebody down-voted this answer.  The only thing I can think is that in some cultural areas (Newfoundland, Canada, for example) the first sentence can mean how long have you been here, or how long will you stay here, or the combined time from when you got here to when you will leave.

Comment: Why is the usage informal? If you are presented to the Queen of Great Britain, her first question might very well be (so I am told) 'have you come far?' Her next could be 'how long are you here for?'. That is pretty formal.